# Rate per min in prometheus

Tags: monitoring, prometheus

If I have a counter in prometheus that is counting the number of incoming http requests for a service and labeling them with the return status code, what would be the right way to get the rate per min grouped by status code? I have two options:

```
sum(rate(http_counter[1m])) by (status_code) * 60
```

OR

```
sum(rate(http_counter[1m])) by (status_code)
```

Basically, I want to know if the result needs to be multiplied by 60 or is that done by `sum` for me? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option is correct. The "rate" function calculates the per-second average rate so you need to multiply by 60 to get the per-minute result.

Comment: Thank you! What is "sum" summing up here?

Comment: It's summing up the other dimensions. See "Aggregation operators" in https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/.